# GoogleMap API infoWindow does not become transparent

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to appear google map API infowindow with half transparent.
Coz i order to appear large sized infowindow with many datas.
Under the infoWindow map's image hide.
But i can not apply transparent (CSS opacity) by InforWindow's property of boxClass.

Please suggest a solution, how to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

[ My code ]

```
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    // content from custom function with many datas i made //
    content: infowincontentHTMLDoor(nmfacil, lat, lon, addrfacil),
    maxWidth: 720,
    boxClass: "infowinclass"  // ?????????
  });
infowindow.open(map, marker);


<style type="text/css">
    .infowinclass {
      opacity: 0.5;  
    }
</style>
```

Comment: `boxClass`? Where did you see that? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions

Comment: Thank your question. I miss coded. and by apply another CSS by DOM selecter, my problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

Self solved.
I apply CSS as following

```
.gm-style > div > div > div > div > div {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: That might solve the problem now, but this is undocumented and the classnames as well as the HTML structure could change at any point.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, I would suggest that you use [Custom Popups](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup) instead of infowindow if you wish to alter it, as the infowindow class does not offer customization and this might cause future problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track, 
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c,
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-t::after { 
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).